# How to get Jenkins build monitor plugin to display badges?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, badge

I am trying to integrate the badges plugin with the jenkins build monitor plugin, which according to the latest release notes should be possible now. (https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin/releases/tag/v1.11%2Bbuild.201701152243)

I have downloaded and installed all required plugins and dependencies.
And added the following code to my Jenkins pipeline in the Post always block.

```
addBadge(icon:"text.gif", text:"cucumber-report", id:"cukerep", link:"http://www.google.com")
```

But after the build finishes without errors, no badges show up in my build monitor plugin view.

I also ticked the show badges box in the build monitor view.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in jenkins monitor view that no badges are shown.

However, if you use the method

```
addShortText (text: "ExampleText", background: "red", border: "1", borderColor: "black", color: "black")
```

the text will be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not using jenkins pipeline but I am using build monitor plugin with groovy postbuild plugin badges. And with the show badges box ticked in the plugin I can see the badges in the build monitor display.

As a complete guess would manager.addBadge work in the pipeline code ?

I suggest installing the Groovy PostBuild plugin and trying something like this.
You could use it instead of addBadge in the pipeline code. 
Or it might offer a clue which would help getting the pipeline addBadge to work.

Groovy PostBuild code to add badges:

```
manager.addShortText("VERSION Black on Lime Green", "black", "limegreen", "0px", "white")
manager.addShortText("OBSOLETE YellowGrey5pxGrey", "yellow", "grey", "5px", "grey")

manager.addBadge("warning.gif", "Warning test")
manager.addWarningBadge("other warning test")
```

e.g. Groovy code to add badges to jobs from another job:
tagging jobs as obsolete when their version does't match latest version.
I give this example code as this is what I currently use and it works.

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildAction
//import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildtriggerbadge.BuildTriggerBadgeAction;

def jobList = [ "job1", "job2" ]

def latestFile = downloadDir + "/latest_version.txt"
try {
  println "read file:" + latestFile
  vLATEST = new File(latestFile).text.trim().replaceAll('-','.')
  println vLATEST
} catch (MissingPropertyException|FileNotFoundException e) { 
  vLATEST = "LATEST version file not found"
  vLATEST = "unknown"
}

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {

  v = "unknown"

  println "ITEM NAME: " + item.getDisplayName()
  println "ITEM DESC: " + item.getDescription()
  if (item.lastBuild) {
    try {
      println "item.WORKSPACE:" + item.WORKSPACE
      println "item.lastBuild.workspace:" + item.lastBuild.workspace;
      vfilename = item.lastBuild.workspace.toString()+"/VERSION.txt"
      v = new File(vfilename).text.trim()
      println v
    } catch (MissingPropertyException|FileNotFoundException e) { 
      // workspace or file not found
      v = "version file not found"
    }
    //currentBuild.setDescription(desc)
  }
  //println item.getDescriptorByName()

  if (item.name in jobList && item.lastBuild) {
    // delete old/other badges
    for(action in item.lastBuild.badgeActions) {
      //println "action:" + action
      //https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Action.html
      if(action instanceof GroovyPostbuildAction) {  // this is safer anyway
        println "action is instanceof GroovyPostbuildAction, remove action:" + action +
            " ts:" + action.toString() +
            " dn:" + action.getDisplayName()
        item.lastBuild.actions.remove(action)
        item.lastBuild.save()
      }
    }

    //item.lastBuild.setDescription(item.lastBuild.description + "\n" + "test set description VERSION:" + v)

    println "check version. vLATEST:" + vLATEST + ", v:" + v
    if (!(vLATEST == "unknown") && !(v.contains(vLATEST))) {
      println "version is not unknown OR does not match so BADGE IT mark build as OLD. vLATEST:" + vLATEST + ", v:" + v
      // badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it badge it
      text = "OLD VERSION: " + v
      item.lastBuild.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createShortText(text, "yellow", "grey", "1px", "darkgrey"));
    } else {
      println "vLATEST:" + vLATEST + " is in v:" + v + " so not marking the build as old."

    }
    // https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/groovy-postbuild/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/groovypostbuild/GroovyPostbuildRecorder.BadgeManager.html#addShortText-java.lang.String-      
  }

}
```

Reference:

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Action.html

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/groovy-postbuild/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/groovypostbuild/GroovyPostbuildRecorder.BadgeManager.html#addShortText-java.lang.String-